# What Python types does TensorFlow accept for Attr's of type "tensor"?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am defining a new Op in C++ which takes in a single attribute of type `tensor`, roughly following [these instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#op_registration). A stripped version of the Op code is below:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"

using namespace tensorflow;

REGISTER_OP("DoStuff")
    .Attr("attr: tensor = { dtype: DT_FLOAT }")
    .Input("in: float")
    .Output("out: float");

class DoStuffOp : public OpKernel {
public:
    explicit DoStuffOp(OpKernelConstruction *context) : OpKernel(context) {
        OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->GetAttr("attr", &attr_));
        // ...
    }

    void Compute(OpKernelContext *context) override {
        // ...
    }

private:
    Tensor attr_;
};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("DoStuff").Device(DEVICE_CPU), DoStuffOp);
```

I can compile the Op into a `.so` file fine. However, I can't figure out how to successfully pass in a value for `attr`. When I run the following in Python:

```
import tensorflow as tf
dostufflib = tf.load_op_library('build/do_stuff.so')
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

A = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
     [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]
X = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0))

Y = dostufflib.do_stuff(X, A)
```

I get `TypeError: Don't know how to convert [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]] to a TensorProto for argument 'attr'`. Nothing I do seems to satisfy the type conversion: `list`, `numpy` array, `tf.Tensor`, `tf.Variable`, etc. How do you pass Python variables into an Op as tensor attributes?

Answer (score 3):

After much more hunting, I found `tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto`, a function that converts a python scalar, python list, numpy ndarray, or numpy scalar into a `tf.TensorProto` object. The following works:

```
A = tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0],[4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
X = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0))

Y = dostufflib.do_stuff(X, A)
```